# Gradle: multi-project build with spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I'm new to Gradle and I'm just getting started with it using a multi-project build. Currently, I'm using spring-boot for services and i have the following directory structure

```
|- api-web (module)
|-- build.gradle
|- api-admin (module)
|-- build.gradle
|- build.gradle (root)
|- settings.gradle
```

Below are the configurations of the **root**

build.gradle (root)

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
}

description = "Company Multi-Project"

ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.2.2.RELEASE'
}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

allprojects {

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {

    group = 'com.company'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    jar {
        enabled = true
    }

    bootJar {
        enabled = false
    }

    dependencies {

        // Lombok annotation processor
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    }
}
```

settings.gradle (root)

```
rootProject.name = 'core'

include 'common'
include 'api-web'
include 'api-admin'
```

Gradle configurations of the **modules**

*api-admin (module)*

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.company.apiadmin.ApiAdminApplication'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

I have added jar closure to prevent error on runtime. This avoids the issue where it fails to run saying "No Manifest"

However even after adding that jar closure, now there is a new issue

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
```

Now I know this says class not found, but my question is **how does it occur and why and how to overcome this**. I have tried most of the suggestions in Medium, StackOverflow and in Blog posts. Nothing helped. Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution for my self, it was a bit tricky to find but finally, I found it

The main point is that you should definitely add the `spring-boot-gradle-plugin` and that will resolve all of your `NoClassDef` errors and `No Manifest Found` errors. To add this you should define a build script in your root build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = "2.2.2.RELEASE"
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion"
    }
}
```

Then you should define the plugins for your project

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
}
```

then you can define all the `subprojects` and `allprojects` as you normally would.

Then in the *modules*, in every sub-module just add these lines

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

bootJar {
    launchScript() // optional
}

dependencies {

    // your module-specific dependencies
}
```

and the dependencies as you normally would.

That's it, now you can build using gradle and execute the `.jar` files as you normally would. :-)

Comment: is there any sample url or github project available?

Comment: unfortunately, I don't. I followed this https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-gradle-multi-module/ back then, I had to do some alterations but everything I did back then is posted here.